# open a folder from my site in order to upload a file

Tags: html, forms, file, upload

I need to allow the user to upload a file from his computer to my site, how do i do that?
 (a browse button)

Any ideas?

**I am looking for a way of doing this with out the `<input type="folder'>` i dont want to have a button and text box i only need a button that will say browse and will open the folder**

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is <input type="file" name="..."> . If you need more details you need to provide more information.

Comment: @CSE, is there a way of doing this with out  <input type="file" name="...">,like i said in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use:

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="thefile" />  <---your "browse" button
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

As for the server-side handling script, this site is littered with TONS of examples on how to handle uploads, so I won't bother posting links.